# Pygame: How to move on to seperate level?

Tags: python, pygame

So, i'm making a platformer game in Pygame. I'm currently a bit stuck with moving onto the next level. I already have an object ready (and collision), so when the player hits that object the intended effect is to move on to the next level. I use lists for all my objects, like enemies, platforms, power-ups. I also use an all sprites class, so all those objects are stored there.
Heres some important code (Tell me if you need anything else):

````
import pygame as pg

#Importing Settings
from settings import *
from Sprites import *


#Class Main Game
class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        # initialize game window, etc
        pg.init()
        pg.mixer.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((screenWidth, screenLength))
        pg.display.set_caption("Wild West: Platformer Edition")
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.running = True
        self.font_name = pg.font.match_font(font_name)

        #Anything that needs to be added to allsprites, or making groups
    def new(self):
        # start a new game
        self.health = 3
        self.score = 0
        self.start_time = pg.time.get_ticks()
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        #Groups
        self.bullets = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.platforms = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.all_enemy = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.attacking = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.powerups = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.endings = pg.sprite.Group()
        #Adding stuff
        self.player = Player(self,self.bullets,self.attacking)
        self.projectile = bullet(self,(self.player.rect.x),(self.player.rect.y))
        self.attack = sword(self,self.player.rect.x, self.player.rect.y)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.player)
        #Ending Object
        self.end = end_level(400,-450)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.end)
        self.endings.add(self.end)
        self.level = 1
        self.platform_list = None
        self.load_level()

        #Enemies spawning
        for ene in enemy_list1:
            e = enemy(*ene)
            self.all_enemy.add(e)
            self.all_sprites.add(e)

        #Platforms spawning
        if self.level == 1
            for plat in self.platform_list1:
                p = Platform(*plat)
                self.all_sprites.add(p)
                self.platforms.add(p)


        #Power ups spawning
        for powerup in powerUpList1:
            pu = powerUp(*powerup)
            self.all_sprites.add(pu)
            self.powerups.add(pu)
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        # Game Loop
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()
            self.load_level()

    def load_level(self):
        if self.level == 1:
            self.platform_list = platform_list1
        if self.level == 2:
            self.platform_list = platform_list2

    def update(self):
        # Game Loop - Update
        # Collision
        self.all_sprites.update()
        if self.player.vel.y > 0:
            hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)
            if hits:
                self.player.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top
                self.player.vel.y = 0

        # Bullet with Enemy
        EBhits = pg.sprite.groupcollide(self.all_enemy, self.bullets, True, True)
        #Sword with Enemy
        Ehits = pg.sprite.groupcollide(self.all_enemy,self.attacking, True, False)
        #Player with Powerups
        puHits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.powerups, True)
        #Player with Enemy
        pHits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player,self.all_enemy, False, False)
        #Player with ending
        endingHits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player,self.endings,False,False)

        #Ending the level
        if endingHits:
            self.all_sprites.empty()
            self.level = 2
            self.ammo = 3
            self.health = 3
            self.new()

        #Power up collision
        if puHits:
            self.player.ammo += 2
        #Sword with Enemy
        if Ehits:
            self.score += 150
        # Bullet with Enemy
        if EBhits:
            self.score += 100
            # Invincibility


        # Player with Enemy
        if pHits:
            self.player.invincin = True
            self.health -= 1

        # Scrolling Screen
        if self.player.rect.top <= screenLength / 4:
            self.player.pos.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)
            for ene in self.all_enemy:
                ene.rect.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)
            #Platform Scrolling
            for plat in self.platforms:
                plat.rect.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)
                if plat.rect.top >= screenLength:
                    plat.kill()

            self.projectile.rect.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)
            #Projectile scrolling
            for bull in self.bullets:
                bull.rect.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)
            #Powerup scrolling
            for powerup in self.powerups:
                powerup.rect.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)

            #End object scrolling
            for End in self.endings:
                End.rect.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)

        # Hitting bottom of the screen
        if self.player.rect.bottom > screenLength + 7:
            self.player.vel.y = -player_jump
            self.player.health -= 1
            self.health -= 1

        #Dying
        if self.health <= 0:
            self.playing = False

        #Time:
        self.timer = pg.time.get_ticks() - self.start_time
        # Loading Level
        self.load_level()

    def events(self):
        # Game Loop - events
        for event in pg.event.get():
            # check for closing window
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                if self.playing:
                    self.playing = False
                self.running = False
            #Shooting
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_j:
                    if self.projectile.rect.x < 800 and self.projectile.rect.x > 0:
                        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
                        if now - self.player.timer >= self.player.cooldown:
                            self.player.timer = now
                            self.player.shoot()
                    else:
                         self.projectile.kill()
                #Attacking
                if event.key == pg.K_h:
                    now1 = pg.time.get_ticks()
                    if now1 - self.attack.timer >= self.attack.cooldown:
                        self.attack.timer = now1
                        self.player.attack()
                # Jumping 
                if event.key == pg.K_w or event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    self.player.jump()

                # Pausing
                if event.key == pg.K_p:
                    self.pause_screen()

        self.load_level()



    def draw(self):
        # Game Loop - draw
        self.screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        self.draw_text(str('Health:'),30,RED,50,15)
        self.draw_text(str(self.health),30,RED,110,15)
        self.draw_text(str('Ammo:'),30,BLUE,50,45)
        self.draw_text(str(self.player.ammo), 30, BLUE, 115, 45)
        self.draw_text(str(self.score),30,YELLOW,screenWidth / 2, 20)
        self.draw_text(str('Score:'), 30, YELLOW, 330,20)
        self.draw_text(str(self.timer / 1000),30, WHITE, 780,20)
        self.draw_text(str('Time:'),30,WHITE,670,20)
        self.load_level()


        # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
        pg.display.flip()

    def show_start_screen(self):
        #game splash/start screen
        waiting = True
        while waiting:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    waiting = False
                    self.running = False
                if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pg.K_h:
                        waiting = False
                    if event.key == pg.K_c:
                        self.control_screen()
                    if event.key == pg.K_q:
                        pg.quit()

            self.screen.blit(MMbackground,(0,0))
            self.draw_text('Wild West: Platformer Edition™',48 ,WHITE ,screenWidth/2 ,screenLength/6.5)
            self.draw_text('Jump across platforms, and Watch out for the bottom!', 30, WHITE, screenWidth/2,screenLength/2)
            self.draw_text('Kill enemies to get score', 30, WHITE, 400, 500)
            self.draw_text('Press H to play.Press C for controls',30 ,WHITE, screenWidth/2, screenLength * 3 / 4)
            pg.display.flip()

    def show_go_screen(self):
        # game over/continue
        if not self.running:
            return
        if death_animation == False:
            waiting = True
            while waiting:
                self.clock.tick(FPS)
                for event in pg.event.get():
                    if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                        waiting = False
                        self.running = False
                    if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pg.K_h:
                            waiting = False
                        if event.key == pg.K_q:
                            pg.quit()




                self.screen.fill(sandybrown)
                self.draw_text('GAME OVER', 48, WHITE, screenWidth / 2, screenLength / 4)
                self.draw_text('Press the H key to retry', 30, WHITE, screenWidth / 2, screenLength * 3 / 4)
                self.draw_text('Press Q to quit', 30, WHITE, 400, 650)
                pg.display.flip()

    def pause_screen(self):
        paused = True
        while paused:
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    pg.quit()

                if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pg.K_p:
                        paused = False

                    elif event.key == pg.K_q:
                        pg.quit()

            self.screen.fill(WHITE)
            self.draw_text(str('PAUSED'),70,BLACK,400,200)
            self.draw_text(str('Press p to unpause'),50,BLACK,400,300)
            self.draw_text(str('Press q to quit game'),50,BLACK,400,400)
            pg.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(5)

    def control_screen(self):
        control = True
        while control:
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    pg.quit()
                if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pg.K_c:
                        control = False

                    if event.key == pg.K_q:
                        pg.quit()
            self.screen.fill(sandybrown)
            self.draw_text(str('CONTROLS'),70,BLACK,400,100)
            self.draw_text(str('A to move left, D to move right'),50,BLACK,400,200)
            self.draw_text(str('W or SPACE to jump'),50,BLACK, 400, 300)
            self.draw_text(str('H for melee attack, J for projectile attack'),40,BLACK,400,400)
            self.draw_text(str('P to pause the game'), 50, BLACK, 400, 500)
            self.draw_text(str('C to return to Main Menu'),40,BLACK, 400, 600)
            pg.display.flip()

    def draw_text(self,text,size,colour,x,y):
        font = pg.font.Font(self.font_name,size)
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, colour)
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        text_rect.midtop = (x,y)
        self.screen.blit(text_surface,text_rect)



g = Game()
g.show_start_screen()
while g.running:
    g.new()
    g.show_go_screen()

pg.quit()
```
````

These are my classes

```
    # Sprite Classes
import pygame as pg
from settings import *

vec = pg.math.Vector2

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self, Game,bullet,sword):
            pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.Game = Game
            self.image = pg.image.load('idle.png')
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = (screenWidth / 2, screenLength / 2)
            self.pos = vec(screenWidth / 2, screenLength / 2)
            self.vel = vec(0, 0)
            self.acc = vec(0,0)
            self.health = 3
            self.ammo = 3
            self.sword = sword
            self.cooldown = 700
            self.bullet = bullet
            self.timer = pg.time.get_ticks()
            self.itimer = pg.time.get_ticks()
            self.left = False
            self.right = False
            self.standing = True
            self.invincin = False
            self.invincinCoolDown= 1300

        def jump(self):
            # Jump only if standing on platforms
            self.rect.x += 1
            hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self,self.Game.platforms,False)
            self.rect.x -= 1
            if hits:
                self.vel.y = -player_jump

        def update(self):
            self.acc = vec(0,player_grav)
            keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
            #Moving and borders

            if keys[pg.K_a]:
                self.acc.x = -player_acc
                self.left = True
                self.right = False
                self.standing = False
            elif keys[pg.K_d]:
                self.acc.x = player_acc
                self.right = True
                self.left = False
                self.standing = False
            else:
                self.standing = True
             #Friction
            self.acc.x += self.vel.x * player_friction
            #Motion
            self.vel += self.acc
            self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc
            self.rect.midbottom = self.pos
            #Borders
            if self.rect.x > 770:
                self.rect.x = 760
            if self.rect.x < -1:
                self.rect.x = 0
        def shoot(self):
            if self.ammo > 0:
                Bullet = bullet(self.Game,self.rect.x,self.rect.top)
                self.Game.all_sprites.add(Bullet)
                self.Game.bullets.add(Bullet)
                self.ammo -= 1

                if self.left:
                    Bullet.speed = 10 * -1
                if self.right:
                    Bullet.speed = 10

        def attack(self):
            if self.right:
                melee = sword(self, self.rect.x + 50, self.rect.top - 15)
                self.Game.all_sprites.add(melee)
                self.Game.attacking.add(melee)
            if self.left:
                melee = sword(self, self.rect.x - 50, self.rect.top - 15)
                self.Game.all_sprites.add(melee)
                self.Game.attacking.add(melee)

class bullet(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, Game,x,y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.image.load('magicBullet.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.Game = Game
        self.Player = Player
        self.speed = 10

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speed

class sword(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,Game,x,y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.image.load('dagger.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.Game = Game
        self.speed = 0.1
        self.cooldown = 75
        self.timer = pg.time.get_ticks()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speed
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.timer >= self.cooldown:
            self.kill()

class Platform(pg.sprite.Sprite):
     def __init__(self,x,y,w,h,colour):
         pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
         self.image = pg.Surface((w,h))
         self.image.fill(colour)
         self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
         self.rect.x = x
         self.rect.y = y

class enemy(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,end,speed):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.image.load("enemy.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.alive = True
        self.health = 3
        self.end = end
        self.speed = speed
        self.timer = pg.time.get_ticks()

    def update(self):
            self.rect.x += self.speed
            now = pg.time.get_ticks()
            if now - self.timer >= self.end:
               self.timer = now
               self.speed *= -1

class powerUp(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.image.load('ammo.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

class end_level(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.image.load('Doors.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

These are settings and lists

```
    import pygame as pg
#Variables
screenWidth = 800
screenLength = 800
#Player Propertes
player_acc = 1
player_friction = -0.06
player_grav = 0.77
player_jump = 18
font_name = 'arial'
background = pg.image.load('Background.png')
MMbackground = pg.image.load('Main_Menu.png')
ending = pg.image.load('Doors.png')
death_animation = False




BROWN = (100,40,0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
sandybrown = (244, 164, 96, 255)

FPS = 60


powerUpList1 = [(75,360)]

platform_list1 =  [(0,screenLength - 40,screenWidth, 40,BROWN),
                  (screenWidth/2 -50,screenLength * 3/4,100,20,GREEN),
                  (75,400, 250, 20,WHITE),
                  (325,200,150,31,BLUE),
                  (60,100,50,20,YELLOW),
                  (625,375,165,15,GREEN),
                  (230,-100,450,20,BROWN),
                  (400,-340,125,10,GREEN)]

enemy_list1 = [(200,-169,3000, 2)]

platform_list2 = [(400,200,300,300,BROWN)]




Platform is just what my class is, and platforms is the group.

    Also, the lists for objects aren't in the main game loop. And show_go_screen is just the game over screen. 
    Any help will be apreciated.
```

Comment: So is platform_list1 for level 1 and platform_list2 for level 2?

Comment: Yea thats the plan at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `platform_list` as an example

You could have a main `platform_list` in the `Game` class, then for each level, assign them to the right list

```
class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        # initialize game window, etc
        self.platform_list = None
        self.level = 1
        self.Load_Level()
```

Have a method that changes the list

```
def Load_Level(self):
    if self.level == 1:
        self.platform_list = platform_list1
        ...
    elif self.level == 2:
        self.platform_list = platform_list2
        ...
```

Or to make it look a bit better, you could have platforms for all levels in one list

```
platform_list1 =  [(0,screenLength - 40,screenWidth, 40,BROWN),
                  (screenWidth/2 -50,screenLength * 3/4,100,20,GREEN),
                  (75,400, 250, 20,WHITE),
                  (325,200,150,31,BLUE),
                  (60,100,50,20,YELLOW),
                  (625,375,165,15,GREEN),
                  (230,-100,450,20,BROWN),
                  (400,-340,125,10,GREEN)]

platform_list2 = [(100,200,300,300,BROWN)]

all_platforms_list = [platform_list1, platform_list2...]



def Load_Level(self):
    self.platform_list = all_platforms_list[self.level]
```

Comment: Ok, so I defined load level, and platform list. Currently, if I change the level to 2 in my code, then the second platform list is loaded. However if I try to change it using my end level object, nothing happens. Probably should have added this earlier but I now added how I actually spawn my platforms in

Comment: @ArjunSharma You did add `self.Load_Level()` in the end level object code. You will also need to spawn the platforms in again, so you will have to empty the sprite groups and then use your spawn code again. Might have to post all of your code so i can exactly see how you are doing everything

Comment: Alright I posted all the code, but its a bit long. The main parts, are new, and update. New is where I spawn the platforms. Update is where the collision is. Also load_level is also important but thats self explanitory.

Comment: Awesome, Could you also post the Sprite code, trying to run it and don't have the platform class etc.

Comment: Also, when the sprite collides with the ending and you make the `level = 2`, you then call `self.new()` which makes `level = 1`. So move it from `new` to `__init__`

Comment: Alright, I added the classes. I'll also add the lists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212316/discussion-between-arjun-sharma-and-the-big-kahuna).